# How to measure distance along a line from a specific point

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network

I have shapefiles of a road network and five points.  What I would like to do is measure the distance from each point along the road network using QGIS, but am struggling to achieve this.  So far, I have tried both v.net.distance and v.net.iso, to no avail.  Each attempt returns 'Error:  Vector map not found'.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the *QGIS Desktop 2.xx with GRASS 7.xx* application then you may need to first **import** your road network and points layer.

You could use:

- `v.in.ogr` - to import your layers using their path or
- `v.in.ogr.qgis` - if your layers are already loaded into QGIS

---

You can access these tools from the menubar:

```
 Plugins > GRASS > Open GRASS Tools
```

[image: GRASS Tools]

---

*Note that you may need to create a GRASS mapset first before using the tools*.

Comment: Thank you, I did try this, but was still unsuccessful.  I think the area is just too large.  I eventually managed to achieve what I wanted using the Rocky Branches - Road Network and Contour plugins.

Comment: @Bernie - Most welcome and glad you found a solution! You should post an **answer** decribing how you solved your problem and accept it by clicking the green-faded tick once posted :)